# .str.split() is removing the last character

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, split

```
def clean_hrefs(allHrefs): 
    links = {'links' : allHrefs}
    df = pd.DataFrame(links).drop_duplicates()
    df = df[df['links'].str.contains('financial|investors|investor|Investors|Investor|INVESTORS|INVESTOR|relations|relation|Relations|Relation|report|filings|news|media')]
    df['segment'] = df['links'].str.split(r'\w/')
    return df
```

clean_hrefs() function accepts a beautiful soup resultant set 'allHrefs' which contains all the href values of a webpage, and assigns it in a dictionary links. df dataframe stores only unique and those links which have certain keywords in them.

After that I tried splitting the links I got so far like :
for example the first link stored in the data frame was :

> https://www.example.com/news-and-media/press-releases?page=/en/pressreleases/example-performs-first-crash-test-of-an-e-scooter-airbag-1769461

The code :

```
df['segment'] = df['links'].str.split(r'\w/')
```

is creating another column called segments and giving the following output :

```
['https://www.example.co', 'news-and-medi', 'press-releases?page=/e', 'pressrelease', 'example-performs-first-crash-test-of-an-e-scooter-airbag-1769461']
```

Where as I want the output to be :

```
['https://www.example.com', 'news-and-media', 'press-releases?page=','en', 'pressreleases', 'example-performs-first-crash-test-of-an-e-scooter-airbag-1769461']
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])`

So you are splitting your `url` on `[a-zA-Z0-9_]/` which in your example will typically including the char preceding the slash.

Assuming you do not want to split on `https://` you can use

```
re.split(r'(?<!\/|:)\/', string)
#['https://www.example.com', 'news-and-media', 'press-releases?page=', 'en', 'pressreleases', 'example-performs-first-crash-test-of-an-e-scooter-airbag-1769461']
```

---

Regex Breakdown

1. `(?<!\/|:)` - Negative Lookbehind to ensure the `/` is not preceded by another slash or `:`
2. `\/` - Match any `/`